# 1D array not printing in for loop, always equal to 0

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm making a blackjack program. In the cardDraw method I have a for loop at the end before the return  that should println each array value, but nothing is displayed when I run the program. Also when I print the array in the main method every values is 0 even though I am setting the values in the method. Could someone please explain why these things are happening? It is probably a logic error but I am having this problem with other methods in the program. We are only allowed to use 1D arrays. Thanks in advance.

One last thing, can you get email notifications for this site

```
public class blackjack {

    public static int [] drawCard(int [] cardValues, int [] otherUserCardValues) {

        int duplicates = 0;

        //fills array with cards    
        for (int count = 0; count == cardValues.length; count++) {

            duplicates = 0;
            cardValues [count] = (int)(Math.random() * 12) + 1;

            //Checks for duplicate cards in one of the hands
            for (int count2 = 0; count2 == cardValues.length; count2++) {

                if (cardValues [count] == cardValues [count2]) {
                    duplicates++;
                } //end of  if (cardValues [count] == cardValues [count2])

            } //end of  for (int count2 = 0; count != 7; count++)

            //Checks for duplicate cards in the other hand
            for (int count2 = 0; count2 == cardValues.length; count2++) {

                if (cardValues [count] == otherUserCardValues [count2]) {
                    duplicates++;
                } //end of  if (cardValues [count] == cardValues [count2])

            } //end of  for (int count2 = 0; count != 7; count++)

            //makes it loop again if there are duplicates
            if (duplicates > 4) {
                count--;
            } //end of  if (duplicates > 4)

        } //end of  for (int count = 0; count != 7; count++)

        for (int count = 0; count == cardValues.length; count++) {
            System.out.println(cardValues[count]);
        }


        return cardValues;

    } //end of  cardDraw


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //user variables
        double money = 0;
        int userCardTotal = 0;
        int userCardCount = 0;

        int [] lowerUserCards = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        int [] higherUserCards = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        int [] userCardValues = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        String [] userCardNames = {"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"};
        String [] userCardSuits = {"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"};

        //dealer variables
        int dealerCardTotal = 0;
        int dealerCardCount = 0;

        int [] lowerDealerCards = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        int [] higherDealerCards = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        int [] dealerCardValues = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        String [] dealerCardNames = {"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"};
        String [] dealerCardSuits = {"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        //methods
        userCardValues = drawCard(userCardValues, dealerCardValues);
        dealerCardValues = drawCard(dealerCardValues, userCardValues);

    } //end of main

} //end of class
```

Comment: I think you want `count < cardValues.length`

Comment: Also for `count2` and the logic for `if (cardValues [count] == cardValues [count2]) ` should be changed to exclue when `count == count2`

Comment: thanks idk how I didn't catch that. honestly wow. love your name btw

Comment: How do you close the question?

Comment: see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63983/can-i-delete-my-own-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `for` loop is simply a slightly dressed up `while` loop.

The loop:

```
for (initial; condition; increment) {
   // do something
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
initial;
while(condition) {
    // do something

    increment;
}
```

with the slight exception that variables described in the initial statment only have the scope of the loop.

When you write:

```
for (int i = 0; i == array.length; i++) {
    doSomething(array[i]);
}
```

the program first declares a variable called `i` and sets it to `0`. It then enters a `while` loop, with the condition: `i == array.length`, which immediately returns `false`, and so the loop exits, before it has completed its first iteration.

The standard syntax for iterating over a loop is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    doSomething(array[i]);
}
```

An (arguably) more readable way is to use a "for-each" loop:

```
for (int value : array) {
    doSomething(value);  // loops over all values in the array, creating a variable value in each iteration
}
```

Even better, using the Java 8 functional style/streams:

```
Arrays.asList(array).forEach(blackjack::doSomething);

// or using streams
Arrays.stream(array).forEach(blackjack::doSomething);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use for loop to do some action for each element in array, you should write it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    doSomething(array[i]);
}
```

where `i < array.length` is a condition that should be true before each iteration.

But in your for loops you write it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i == array.length; i++) {
    doSomething(array[i]);
}
```

So if array is not empty, then this loop won't do even one iteration. And if array is empty, it will even throw an exception because you'll try to access array[0].